# Using sklearn and keras to check how reliable a cumulative sum is for the long term

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sklearn-pandas

Part of my CSV file:

```
cumulative_sum
0.2244
0.75735
1.74845
1.93545
2.15985
2.8611
1.8611
2.2538
2.88025
3.83395
2.83395
5.0312
5.4426000000000005
5.5735
4.5735
3.5735
2.5735
3.38695
2.38695
1.3869500000000001
1.7048500000000002
2.47155
3.6309500000000003
4.1078
4.640750000000001
3.6407500000000006
4.3420000000000005
3.3420000000000005
3.6318500000000005
3.8282000000000003
4.08065
3.0806500000000003
3.7725500000000003
4.2868
3.2868000000000004
3.9974000000000003
4.7454
3.7454
4.7178
5.129200000000001
5.297500000000001
4.297500000000001
4.708900000000002
3.7089000000000016
```

I'm wanting to analyze how reliable is the growth of this cumulative sum for the long term:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

df = pd.read_csv("gradual_cumsum.csv")

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data = scaler.fit_transform(df)

train_size = int(len(data) * 0.8)
test_size = len(data) - train_size
train, test = data[0:train_size,:], data[train_size:len(data),:]

X_train = train[:, 0:1]
y_train = train[:, 1:2]
X_test = test[:, 0:1]
y_test = test[:, 1:2]
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

test_loss = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)

print(f'Test Loss: {test_loss}')
```

But all Epoch's generate `loss: nan`:

```
Epoch 1/100
849/849 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: nan
```

And obviously the end result is:

```
Test Loss: nan
```

What am I missing that is generating this failure that fails to verify the data?

Comment: Did you check your `X_train` for nan values? Also scaling should be done after the train-test split otherwise you'll have data leak.

Comment: Hi @Frightera i check and ```X_train``` does not contain ```nan``` values.

Comment: Maybe your targets have nan values? I would say gradient explosion is the problem but Adam is an adaptive optimizer so it should not be a problem here.

Comment: Hi @Frightera the data does not change from those that I put as an example in the CSV, they are just in a larger amount, more specifically 1060 lines.